# Cannot import class router.Routes in ApplicationLoader on Play 2.5

Tags: scala, playframework, dependency-injection

I'm having a problem with a migration to Play 2.5 with Scala. I had to start using DependencyInjection and after reading all the Play Framework 2.5 migration documentation and making all the corresponding implementations I arrived to an strange problem. Play indicates that class Routes should be automatically generated with the new DependencyInjection schema but when I tried to import the class in my custom ApplicationLoader, the compiler tells me that cannot resolve symbol "router". Below is part of my code, hope you can help me with this, thanks!

```
import controllers.Assets
import controllers.api.clients.ClientsController
import play.api.ApplicationLoader.Context
import play.api._
import play.api.libs.ws.ahc.AhcWSComponents
import router.Routes

class AppLoader extends ApplicationLoader {
  def load(context: Context) = {
    LoggerConfigurator(context.environment.classLoader).foreach {
      _.configure(context.environment)
    }

    new AppComponents(context).application
  }
}

class AppComponents(context: Context) extends BuiltInComponentsFromContext(context) with AhcWSComponents {

  lazy val clientsController: ClientsController = new ClientsController(wsClient)
  lazy val assets: Assets = new Assets(httpErrorHandler)

  lazy val router = new Routes(
    httpErrorHandler,
    clientsController,
    assets
  )
}
```

Comment: Is it referring to the symbol router at import or te lazy val?

Answer (score 6):

Check the following:

1. Make sure your `build.sbt` contains `routesGenerator := InjectedRoutesGenerator`
2. Execute `playCompileEverything` in `sbt` and refresh your project in your IDE